# CHUNKSTATE and STAT_CHUNK are undefined

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, directx, visual-studio-2017

I got these errors when upgrading this https://github.com/LestaD/SourceEngine2007 from `VB2005`, And i can't seem to solve the issue...
The errors are caused by the dependencies that were included later

Error List:

```
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'STAT_CHUNK'

Error   C3646   'GetChunkType': unknown override specifier  

Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CHUNKSTATE'
```

These are the files:

..\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\atlmfc\include\atlhandler.h

..\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h

General Properties:

```
Target Platform: Windows 10 

Windows SDK Version: 10.0.14393.0

Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2017 (v141)

Configuration Type: Dynamic Library (.dll)

Use of MFC: Use MFC in a Shared DLL

Character Set: Use Multi-Byte Character Set

Common Language Runtime Support: Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)

.NET Target Framework Version:
```

VC++ Directories:

```
Executable Directories: $(VC_ExecutablePath_x86);$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath);$(VS_ExecutablePath);$(MSBuild_ExecutablePath);$(SystemRoot)\SysWow64;$(FxCopDir);$(PATH);

Include Directories: C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft DirectX SDK %28June 2010%29\Include;$(IncludePath)

Reference Directories: $(VC_ReferencesPath_x86);

Library Directories: C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft DirectX SDK %28June 2010%29\Lib\x86;$(LibraryPath)

Library WinRT Directories: $(WindowsSDK_MetadataPath);

Source Directories: $(VC_SourcePath);

Exclude Directories: $(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);$(MSBuild_ExecutablePath);$(VC_LibraryPath_x86);
```

Rest of the properties look standard

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

The structure  `STAT_CHUNK` and the enum `CHUNKSTATE` are not supported for win10.

Scroll down to bottom in the below links,you can notice that the end of client support is "Windows7"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691016(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691020(v=vs.85).aspx

Also the documentation suggests to use "**Windows search**" for rapid searching.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965362(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is there a way to update MSVC? or can i change some properties to make it compile for windows 7?

Comment: In target platform version of your project settings, you can see only 10 and 8. So my guess is nothing much you can do from compiler side. Are those libraries are from a vendor? If so get the right ones targeting windows 10 from the vendor. If those dependencies are developed by you, look into examples in this link, so may help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872109(v=vs.85).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940336(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Alright i understand that compiling on Windows 10 isn't going to work. So I'm guessing only way to compile this is to move to Windows 7. Thank you for your time, Really appreciate it that you've help me with my situation

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 can of course compile applications that target Windows 7. See [Visual Studio 2017 Platform Targeting and Compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs) for an overview. The target platform version is really only meaningful for UWP development. How to target Windows 7 (or Vista) is explained under [General Property Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/general-property-page-project).